# How do I get Google Sheets to Find First Instance at or above a Numerical Value in a Column of Values?

Tags: google-sheets, match, matching, google-sheets-formula

I am building a Google sheet to count the # of days a dividend stock returns to or above the price it closed before the ex-dividend date.

So I have a table with two columns for the stock I'm looking at, with 1st column being the Date, 2nd column the high price the stock hit during that day.

So in column D, I have the date before ex-div date, and in column E, I have the stock closing price on the date in E.

In columns G & H I have the next 3 months worth of days (in column G) and stock daily high prices (in column H).

I tried to use `=match` to count the days until the stock price returns to equal or above the closing price on the date in column E, but while it returns a numerical value, it is not accurate.

```
=MATCH(E2,H2:H,1)
```

I'd like the formula to return the number of days the stock took to recover.

Comment: I tried both 0 and -1, and they all give inaccurate values.

Comment: Here is a link, hope it works: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19I4HqFcMmuf3swbvOzBJMysXK56KhRAjeNFoDr_81RM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what should be the result?

Answer (score 1):

maybe like:

```
=DAYS(INDIRECT("G"&MATCH(E2, H:H, 0)), D2)
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

> how to get to the first date from Column G that matches or exceeds the price in column E (and return the # of days in F2 for that date)

```
=DAYS(QUERY(G2:H, "select G where H >= "&E2&"limit 1", 0), D2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hmm, looks like a very interesting idea, but it's not accurate. On the sheet, you can also see a graph that has a red line, which is the recovery line, that makes it easier to visually tell how many days it took till recovery.

Comment: Or, as can be seen in the screenshot you posted, HST recovered and exceeded the E2 price on the very fist day of the sequence (H2), so the formula should return 1.

Comment: in that case try: `=DAYS(H2, D2)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, player0. =DAYS(H2, D2) returns the correct number of days. The piece that I haven't figured out yet is how to get to the first date from Column G that matches or exceeds the price in column E (and return the # of days in F2 for that date). Appreciate your help so far very much!

Comment: It looks like I would have to likely include a query inside the DAYS() function, with H:H as the data, and the query would be something that reads through Column H, starting from H2, until the H value is equal or greater than E2. The corresponding G data for that H value is the data that I need to use in the DAYS() function.

Answer (score -1):

```
=min(filter(date column, value column>minimum value))
```

Comment: Can you specify how this would exactly apply to the example (similar to the other answer), i.e. so that it can be executed in the spreadsheet?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Agree with Mustafa, some additional context would be great, especially for future searchers that may find this post.